# Using script to find string of text up until first html tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a service that is returning a message. That message may be a combination of plain text or an html formatted text.

```
ex1: "This is a message"

ex2: "<p> This is also a message <p/>"

ex3: "This is also a <strong> message </strong>"
```

The thing we would like to do is come up with a script that would return as much plain text up until the first tag. So in the examples above:

1. would return "This is a message.
2. would return ""
3. would return "This is also a"

I am not sure what approach is the best to do this. Can i accomplish this using Regex or JS. I know Regex can easily return text between two tags, but what i am looking for is a little different. Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/269970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to match anything except `<`s, starting at the beginning of the string:

```
match = subject.match(/^[^<]*/)[0];
```

This fails if `<`s could occur in comments/quoted strings  before the first HTML tag, but that might not be a problem.

Test on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka4ny/)

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Anchor the match to the start of the string.
[^<]   # Match any character that's not a <
*      # zero or more times (as many as possible).
```

Comment: Have you tested for last example.

Comment: Can you share a link where you tested it?

Comment: will it work for `This is also a <strong> message </strong> string`

Comment: In that example i would still want "This is also a"... so it would work for what i need it for.

Comment: @Braj: Of course it will, how is that so difficult to see or test?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for the sample. Just so i can learn, can you explain what the match is searching for? Is it just the "<" character?

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)